# What is the way collide UILabel in UIImage?

Tags: iphone

I have a task to do. I have a big image like a country and different names like name of the states in a country which are UILabels. My task is if I place the label on any state in the UIImageview, it should check whether I placed it on correct place or not.

Can anyone let me know the logic how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very unclear.  What does "correctly placed" mean?

Surely you don't expect the software to analyze the graphic, determine the state boundaries, workout which state is which, then compare the state to the title of the label that you've placed over it?

Sounds like you just need an array of (x,y) values which tell you where to position each label:

```
NSArray *points = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 2.0)],
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(3.0, 4.0)],
                     nil];
```

Or you could write code to read them from a file, but that's obviously more work.

Comment: Hi Tarmes, Thanks for answering, I am new to this iPhone can you please let me know how to create array of(x,y) values to fix the position for an image. correctly placed means"to place the label exactly on the desired position like placing Newyork Label on newyork image

Comment: i jus need an example please help me--Thanks

Comment: I've edited the answer to include an array initialization.

Comment: Oh, and I see that you're new here.  If you're happy with the response, please click the tick to accept the answer :)

Comment: @tarmesin: Thanks, i have doubts, I have a single image and i need to set different CGPointMake in it for ex: a country image were i want to set it for each states, so that i can fix it to the label, how can i judge the (x,Y) value